# sql Select the max value within a combination of starting time and ending time

Tags: sql, max

I have a database as the data table below. Its a standard Open High Low Close Database. I wanna select the date, start-time, end-time, max([high] over ***The period of time) , and Close

**Data Table**

| date | time | high |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20100104 | 94000 | 21850 |
| 20100104 | 94500 | 21903 |
| 20100104 | 95000 | 21875 |
| 20100104 | 95500 | 21855 |
| 20100104 | 100000 | 21904 |
| 20100104 | 100500 | 21922 |
| 20100104 | 101000 | 21935 |
| 20100104 | 101500 | 21949 |
| 20100104 | 102000 | 21954 |
| 20100104 | 102500 | 21987 |
| 20100104 | 103000 | 22017 |
| 20100104 | 103500 | 22049 |
| 20100104 | 104000 | 22024 |
| 20100104 | 104500 | 22015 |
| 20100104 | 105000 | 21988 |
| 20100104 | 105500 | 21996 |
| 20100104 | 110000 | 21966 |
| 20100104 | 110500 | 21989 |
| 20100104 | 111000 | 21983 |
| 20100104 | 111500 | 21942 |
| 20100104 | 112000 | 21937 |
| 20100104 | 112500 | 21925 |
| 20100104 | 113000 | 21927 |
| 20100104 | 113500 | 21956 |
| 20100104 | 114000 | 21950 |
| 20100104 | 114500 | 21904 |
| 20100104 | 115000 | 21898 |
| 20100104 | 115500 | 21896 |
| 20100104 | 120000 | 21915 |
| 20100104 | 120500 | 21900 |
| 20100104 | 121000 | 21850 |
| 20100104 | 121500 | 21845 |
| 20100104 | 122000 | 21856 |
| 20100104 | 122500 | 22000 |
| 20100104 | 142500 | 21855 |
| 20100104 | 143000 | 21900 |
| 20100104 | 143500 | 21839 |
| 20100104 | 144000 | 21758 |
| 20100104 | 144500 | 21751 |
| 20100104 | 145000 | 21763 |
| 20100104 | 145500 | 21786 |
| 20100104 | 150000 | 21804 |
| 20100104 | 150500 | 21794 |
| 20100104 | 151000 | 21803 |
| 20100104 | 151500 | 21814 |
| 20100104 | 152000 | 21850 |
| 20100104 | 152500 | 21835 |
| 20100104 | 153000 | 21853 |
| 20100104 | 153500 | 21874 |
| 20100104 | 154000 | 21900 |
| 20100104 | 154500 | 21842 |
| 20100104 | 155000 | 21833 |
| 20100104 | 155500 | 21819 |
| 20100104 | 160000 | 21861 |
| 20100104 | 160500 | 22000 |
| 20100104 | 161000 | 22000 |
| 20100105 | 94000 | 22079 |
| 20100105 | 94500 | 22095 |
| 20100105 | 95000 | 22095 |
| 20100105 | 95500 | 22098 |
| 20100105 | 100000 | 22109 |
| 20100105 | 100500 | 22089 |
| 20100105 | 101000 | 22061 |
| 20100105 | 101500 | 22033 |
| 20100105 | 102000 | 22045 |
| 20100105 | 102500 | 22103 |
| 20100105 | 103000 | 22071 |
| 20100105 | 103500 | 22092 |
| 20100105 | 104000 | 22093 |
| 20100105 | 104500 | 22184 |

**Result**

| date | start-time | end-time | high among the period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20100104 | 94000 | 94000 | 21850 |
| 20100104 | 94000 | 94500 | 21903 |
| 20100104 | 94000 | 95000 | 21903 |
| 20100104 | 94000 | 95500 | 21903 |
| 20100104 | 94000 | 100000 | 21904 |
| 20100104 | 94000 | 100500 | 21922 |
| 20100104 | 94000 | 101000 | 21935 |
| 20100104 | 94000 | 101500 | 21949 |
| 20100104 | 94000 | 102000 | 21954 |
| … | … | … | … |
| … | … | … | … |
| 20100104 | 94500 | 94500 | 21903 |
| 20100104 | 94500 | 95000 | 21903 |
| 20100104 | 94500 | 95500 | 21903 |
| 20100104 | 94500 | 100000 | 21904 |
| 20100104 | 94500 | 100500 | 21922 |
| 20100104 | 94500 | 101000 | 21935 |
| 20100104 | 94500 | 101500 | 21949 |
| 20100104 | 94500 | 102000 | 21954 |
| … | … | … | … |
| … | … | … | … |
| 20100105 | 94000 | 94000 | 22079 |
| 20100105 | 94000 | 94500 | 22095 |
| 20100105 | 94000 | 95000 | 22095 |
| 20100105 | 94000 | 95500 | 22098 |
| 20100105 | 94000 | 100000 | 22109 |
| 20100105 | 94000 | 100500 | 22109 |
| 20100105 | 94000 | 101000 | 22109 |
| 20100105 | 94000 | 101500 | 22109 |
| 20100105 | 94000 | 102000 | 22109 |
| … | … | … | … |
| … | … | … | … |
| 20100105 | 94500 | 94500 | 22095 |
| 20100105 | 94500 | 95000 | 22095 |
| 20100105 | 94500 | 95500 | 22098 |
| 20100105 | 94500 | 100000 | 22109 |
| 20100105 | 94500 | 100500 | 22109 |
| 20100105 | 94500 | 101000 | 22109 |
| 20100105 | 94500 | 101500 | 22109 |
| 20100105 | 94500 | 102000 | 22109 |
| … | … | … | … |
| … | … | … | … |
| … | … | … | … |
| … | … | … | … |

How should i write this?

Comment: What is your DBMS? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? Please tag your request accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-join the table to get all start and end times. Then select the maximum high in a subquery in the select clause.

```
select
  s.date, s.time as start_time, e.time as end_time,
  (
    select max(high)
    from mytable t
    where t.date = s.date
    and t.time between s.time and e.time
  ) as max_high
from mytable s
join mytable e on e.date = s.date and e.time >= s.time
order by s.date, s.time, e.time;
```

Comment: awesome !!! it takes me a day still cannot make it !